# pagination using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i want to create a pagination using ajax but i am getting trouble for it.
i use folliwing ajax function for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
     $('#ajax_pagi a').click(function(e){          
       var url = $(this).attr('href');
         $.ajax({
           url:url,
           type:'POST',
           success:function(data){          
               $('body').html(data);
           }
         });
         e.preventDefault(); 
         return false;
    });
  }); 
     </script>
```

and following is pagination link

```
<ul id="ajax_pagi"> <?php echo  $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></ul>
```

it refresh page when click on the next page link.
so any one can help me to solve this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the first click works with ajax, or not at all?

Comment: where is `<a>` tag  in your id `ajax_pagi ` ???

Comment: <a> tag is coming dynamically from create_links() function @Abbas Gabru

Comment: first click work after that it refresh page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of event delegation. for the first time it will work, next time it will refresh the page.

So use `on()` instead of `click()`.

```
$(document).on("click","#ajax_pagi a",function(e){          
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
     $.ajax({
       url:url,
       type:'POST',
       success:function(data){          
           $('body').html(data);
       }
     });
     e.preventDefault(); 
     return false;
});
```

For current page href will be equal to `#`, if user click on that it will generate 404 error.

Add if() for ajax

```
if(url != "#") {
   //ajax here
}
```

Comment: sir, its working..
but some time  it takes so many times for response

Comment: i don't know about UN..?

Comment: whatever but i can't understand what you want to say

Comment: i think ajax call automatically after some time

Comment: there is so many file calling like following..

jquery-... > eval (line 4)
GET http://localhost/HRMS/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js?_=1448453129015
 
200 OK
  0ms 
jquery-... > eval (line 4)
GET http://localhost/HRMS/js/jquery-ui.js?_=1448453129016
 
200 OK
  10ms 
jquery-... > eval (line 4)
GET http://localhost/HRMS/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?_=1448453129017
 
200 OK
  0ms

Comment: response come with full page including header and footer so..
i use ('body').html(data)  so it replace entire page

Comment: This wrong.... Load only required part.. Only table rows.... It ll work faster....

Comment: but sir it returns entire page form controller.

Comment: There create one mire view to load only table... Don't load entire page... It's bad idea....

Comment: but sir how to create it

Comment: when ajax is calling following my answer function is called..
and this function is called when first time page is call.

Comment: You are calling same file in Ajax... Instead if that, create one more page which will generate only table instead of full page...

Comment: i create a new view contain only <tbody> but it not's work

Comment: a variable that pass to foreach is undefined

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96172/discussion-on-answer-by-niranjan-n-raju-pagination-using-ajax-in-codeigniter).